# Convert a code of graphics to SVG/PNG image

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, adobe, createjs

I have an a school project in animate, I had a HDD crash and lost my original file of adobe animate (.fla). I need to edit some vectors but I do not have the original files due this I need to convert the code in a svg image.

I have create the project on a Windows PC and use animate html5 javascript mode

```js
this.shape_4 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_4.graphics.f("#FF3300").s().p("AlQFlQgDgIABgTQACgTgDgIQgHgPgBgHQgCgGACgJQABgLAAgGQAAgHgGgNQgGgPgBgGIAAgPQABgJgBgFQgBgMgEgKQgHgUgEgWQgCgZgEgLQgGgNAAgGQgBgEAAgHIABgMQAAgJgDgNIgFgSIgGgkQgFgagKgbIgIgYIgCgGIACAAIAXgMQARgIAegGQAHgGAJgFQATgMAWgDIAAAAQAIAAAHAEIAGgEIABgBIAFAIQACAEABAHIAFAKQADALADAmQAGAuAAAZIgCAfIACAKIAAAeQgBASACAMIAGAVQAFAPABAHQABAMgBASIgDAcQgDAXAJAMQAGAGAKABQALgBADgHQACgDgBgGIAAgBIBzgvIABADQABAFAHAJQAEAJAAAWIgBA6IAAAVIgIAAIACABIhsAnQgcALgNACIgnAHIgpAMIgYAJIgBgEgAHoEpIgOgnIgGgZQgHgfgPgeQArgsArg4IAuhBQAGgGAJgNIAKgRIADAAQAKgDACgHQABgJgHgKIghgzIgOgUQgWgggMgOQgQgTgRgMQAbgbARgWQALgSAKgKQAKgJAMgHQAKAUAgAnQAeAlAKAXQALAaAHAHQAGAEAHABIADACQAIADAIgCQAGgDAHgHIAMgMQAQgSAlgcIAogeQALAJANARIAVAbQAQATAMALQAKAMAJAEIgJAJQgMAOgSARIgeAdIhFBCIgPAKIgPANQgiAegHAIQgfAeg2A9Qg4A/gdAcQgnAlgUAXIgBgDgAtlEcQgLACgJgBIABgUQgKgTgCgiIgHh4QgDgSAGgLIAHgIQgBgSgCgOQgBgLgGgVQgCgMAAgZIAAgmIgFgnQgHhBgEhKQgCgKADgJIACgCIgEgHIAKAAIAKgCQADgCADgHIAEgIQBGAACBATQAsAHAaAHQAbAHAeARQAMAGARAMQAXATALAQQANAVACAYQABAdgOAWIgTAXIgRAbQgKARgKAHQgKAJgZAKIg/AXQgkANgdAHIgdAHQgQAFgLAHIgDADIACAHQAIAfADAsIADBMQAAAQgCAKIABAHIgDABIgEAJQgJARgeAMQgPAFgOAAQgOAAgMgGgAsgh/QgHAIAAAGQAAAEAGAJQAEAHABALIABAUQAAAUAIAKIABAAQADACADAEQAJAFAQAAIAdgBQANgBAPgJQAJgFASgMQATgPADgOQADgLgIgRQgFgKgFgEQgFgEgHgCIgOgBIhDgEQgTAAgDgIIgMAAQgBAEgIAIgABhD5QgJgBgNgEIgWgIQgRgHgYgGIghgGIAAgIIgBgPQAAgKAFgVQAGgVABgKIABgNIAAgPIADgJIAFgKQABgIAAgMIAAgWQgCgTACgMIAFgIQACgEABgDQABgHAAgMQgBgNABgHQABgGAHgNQAEgOgDgbQgCgQAEgSIAIgUQACgHgBgQQgCgPACgHIAGgOQAEgJAAgFIAAgLQgBgHABgEQABgEADgHIAEgJQADgIgCgSQgBgRACgIIACgFQANABANgDIAagGQAWgDAHgDIAXgJQAPgFAKgBIASgBQALgBAGgCIAEAXIAUBfIAFAaIAEAaIAFASIAGAXIAKAoIAKAoIATBGQAEALACAKIAEAYIAFAUQAGAPAEARQAEAOAFALQABAFAGAMQAHARAEAWIgBAAIhhAYQgKADgFgDQgHgFAAgLQgDgjgSgfIgFgBQgDgEgDgCIAAgCIgjAKQgRAFgHAFQgIAFgHALQgFAIAAALIAAATQAAAMgCAGQgBAEgDAHQgDAGgBAFQgBAEABAHIAAALIAAACIgMgBgACNhxQgFABgCADQgEAJAAAIIgCA9QgCAWgEAKQgHAMgBAFQgBAIAEAHQAEAHAHACQAEACAIAAIAPACQAXADAHgMQAFgJgFgNIgFgJQgDgGAAgCIgBgMQAAgJgCgEIgGgMQgDgFABgNQABgMgDgGIgEgGQgDgDAAgDIgBgHIgBgHQAAgKgHgBQgBAAAAgBQgBAAAAAAQAAAAgBAAQgBgBAAAAIgDABg");
this.shape_4.setTransform(1.5,-0.5);

this.shape_5 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_5.graphics.f("#FF6600").s().p("AlxGCQgDgJACgTQABgVgDgJQgIgQgBgIQgBgHABgKQACgMgBgFQAAgIgGgOQgGgRgBgGIAAgQQABgKgBgEQgCgOgEgLQgIgWgEgXQgDgbgEgMQgGgPgBgGQgBgFABgHIAAgNQAAgKgDgNIgFgVIgHgmQgGgdgKgcIgJgbIgCgGIACgBIAZgLQATgJAhgHQAIgGAJgGQAVgNAYgDIAAgBQAJAAAIAGIAGgGIABAAIAGAJQACAEABAHQADAFACAGQAEAMADApQAHAyAAAbIgCAiIACALIgBAgQAAAUACALQACAJAFAQQAFAOABAJQABANgBATIgDAeQgDAaAKAMQAGAIALgBQAMABADgJQACgDAAgHIAAgBIB+gyIAAADQABAFAIALQAFAJAAAXIgCBAIABAWIgJAAIACABIh2ArQgfALgPACIgqAIIgtANIgaAJIgCgEgAIXFCIgPgrIgHgbQgIgigQggQAvgwAvg8IAyhHQAHgHAKgNQAGgMAFgGIAEgBQAKgCACgJQACgIgIgMIgkg2IgPgWQgYgkgOgOQgSgVgSgNQAegdASgYQAMgTALgMQALgJAOgHQALAVAiAqQAhAoALAZQANAcAHAIQAGAEAIACIADABQAJAEAJgDQAHgDAIgIIAMgMQASgVApgdIAsghQALAKAOASIAYAeQASAUAMANQALANAKADIgKALQgNAOgTATIgiAfIhLBHIgQAMIgRANQglAggIAKQgiAgg7BCQg+BFggAeQgqAogWAZIgBgDgAu5E0QgMABgJAAIABgWQgMgVgCgkIgIiDQgCgTAGgLIAHgJQAAgUgDgPQgBgMgHgWQgBgOAAgbIAAgpIgGgrQgIhFgEhRQgDgKAEgKIACgCIgEgIIAKAAIALgCQAEgCADgIIAFgJQBMABCNAUQAxAIAcAIQAeAHAhATQANAGASAOQAaATAMASQAOAXACAaQACAfgPAXQgGAIgPASIgTAdQgLARgLAJQgLAKgcALIhEAYQgoAOggAIIggAIQgRAGgMAGIgDADIABAIQAJAjADAuQACARACBCQAAAQgCAMIABAIIgDAAIgEAKQgKATghANQgRAFgPAAQgQAAgNgGgAttiJQgIAIAAAGQAAAFAGAKQAFAIABAMIACAVQAAAVAIALIABAAQAEACADAGQAKAEARAAIAggBQAOgBARgKQAKgFATgOQAVgPAEgQQACgLgIgTQgFgLgGgDQgFgEgIgDIgPgBIhKgFQgVAAgDgJIgOAAQAAAFgJAJgABqEOQgKgBgOgFIgYgJQgSgIgbgFIgjgHIgBgKIgCgOQAAgNAGgVQAHgXABgLIABgPIAAgPQABgEADgGIAEgLQACgIAAgOIAAgYQgDgTADgOIAFgJIAEgIQABgGAAgPQgBgOABgGQABgIAHgNQAFgPgEgdQgBgSAEgTIAIgWQADgIgBgQQgCgRACgHIAHgQQAEgKAAgGIAAgLQgBgHABgEQABgFADgHQAEgHAAgEQAEgIgCgTQgCgUADgIIACgEQAOAAAOgEIAdgFQAYgEAHgDQAJgCARgIQAQgFAMgCIATgBQAMAAAHgCIAEAYIAWBnIAGAcIAEAdQADAOACAFIAHAYIALAtIALAqIAUBMQAFALADAMIADAaIAGAVQAGAQAFATQAEAQAGALQABAGAHANQAHARAFAaIgBAAIhrAZQgKADgGgDQgIgFAAgMQgDgngUghQgCgBgDAAQgDgEgEgCIAAgCQgcAIgLACQgSAGgHAFQgJAFgIAMQgFAJAAAMIgBAVQAAAMgCAIIgEALQgEAHAAAEQgBAFAAAIIABALIAAACIgOAAgACah7QgFACgCAEQgEAIAAAKIgDBBQgCAZgFAKQgHANgBAFQgBAJAFAIQAEAHAHACQAEADAKABIAQABQAZACAIgMQAGgJgGgOIgFgKQgEgGAAgDIgBgOQAAgIgCgFIgHgNQgDgFABgOQABgOgDgGIgEgGQgEgEAAgDIgBgIIgBgHQAAgLgIgBQgBgBAAAAQgBAAAAgBQgBAAAAAAQgBAAgBAAIgDAAg");
this.shape_5.setTransform(1.8,-0.3);

this.shape_6 = new cjs.Shape();
this.shape_6.graphics.f("#003366").s().p("AkyEmQgDgHABgPQACgQgDgGQgGgNgBgGQgCgFACgHIABgOQAAgGgFgKIgHgSIAAgMQABgIgBgDQgBgKgDgJQgHgQgDgSQgDgUgDgKQgFgLgBgEQgBgEABgGIAAgKQAAgHgCgKIgFgQIgGgcQgEgWgJgWIgHgUIgCgFIABAAIAVgKQAQgGAcgFQAGgFAIgEQARgKAUgDIAAAAQAHAAAHAEIAFgEIABgBIAFAHQACAEAAAFQADAEACAEQADAJACAgQAHAmAAAUIgCAZIACAJIgBAYQgBAPACAJIAGASQAEAMABAGQABAKgBAOIgCAYQgDATAIAJQAGAGAJAAQAJAAADgGQACgDgBgFIAAAAIBpgnIABACQAAAEAHAIQAEAIAAARIgBAxIAAAQIgHAAIABABIhiAhQgaAIgMACIgjAGIglAKIgWAHIgBgDgAG8D1IgMggIgGgVQgGgagOgZQAogkAmguIAqg1QAGgGAIgJQAFgKAEgEIADgBQAJgBACgHQABgHgHgJIgdgpQgIgLgFgFQgUgbgLgMQgPgPgQgKQAZgXAPgRQAKgPAJgJQAKgHALgFQAJAQAdAgQAbAeAJATQALAVAGAGQAFADAGACIADABQAHADAIgCQAGgCAGgGIALgKQAOgQAigWIAlgZQAKAHALAOIAUAXIAZAZQAJAKAJADIgJAIIgbAZIgcAXIg+A2IgOAJIgNAKQgfAZgHAHQgcAYgyAzQgzA0gaAXQgjAfgTASIgBgCgAsYDqIgSABIABgRQgJgPgCgcIgHhjQgCgPAGgJIAFgGQAAgQgCgLQgBgJgGgQIgBggIAAgfIgEggQgHg1gDg9QgDgJADgHIACgCIgEgFIAJAAIAJgCQAEgCACgGIAEgGQA/AAB2AQQAoAFAYAGQAYAGAcAOQAKAFAQAKQAVAQAKANQAMARACAUQABAYgNARIgRAUIgQAWQgJANgJAHQgJAHgXAIIg5ASQghAMgbAFIgaAGQgPAFgJAFIgDACIABAGQAIAaACAkIADA+QAAANgCAJIABAGIgCAAIgEAHQgIAPgbAKQgOAEgMAAQgOAAgLgFgArZhoQgHAGAAAFQAAAEAGAIQAEAFAAAJIACAQQAAAQAHAJIAAAAQAEABADAFQAIADAOAAIAagBQAMgBAOgHIAYgOQASgMADgMQACgJgHgOQgEgIgFgDQgEgDgHgCIgMgBIg+gEQgRAAgCgGIgMAAQgBADgHAHgABYDNQgIAAgMgEIgUgHQgPgGgXgEIgcgFIgBgHIgBgMQAAgJAFgRQAFgRABgIIABgLIAAgMQAAgDADgFIAEgIQABgGAAgLIAAgSQgCgPACgKQAAgCAEgFIADgGQABgFAAgKIAAgQQABgGAGgKQAEgLgDgXQgBgNADgOQAHgOAAgDQACgGgBgMQgBgNACgGQAAgDAFgIQAEgIAAgFIAAgIQgBgGABgDIADgJQADgFAAgDQADgHgBgOQgCgPADgGIACgEQALABAMgDIAYgEQAUgDAGgCIAVgIQAOgEAJgBIAQgBQAKAAAGgCIAEATIASBOIAEAVIAEAWQACALACAEIAGASIAJAiIAJAgIARA6QAEAIACAJIADAUIAFAQQAFAMAEAPQAEAMAEAIIAHAPQAGANAEATIgBAAIhZATQgIADgFgDQgGgDAAgKQgDgdgRgaIgEAAQgDgEgDgBIAAgCIggAIQgPAFgGAEQgIAEgGAJQgEAHAAAJIgBAPQAAAKgCAGIgDAIIgEAJIAAAJIAAAJIAAACIgLgBgACAhdQgEACgCACQgEAGAAAIIgCAyQgCATgDAHQgGAKgBAEQgBAGAEAGQADAGAGACQAEACAIAAIANABQAVACAHgKQAEgGgEgLIgFgIQgDgFAAgBIgBgKQAAgHgBgEIgGgJQgDgFABgKQABgKgCgFIgEgFQgDgDAAgCIgBgHIgBgFQAAgHgHgCQAAAAAAAAQgBgBAAAAQgBAAAAAAQgBAAAAAAIgDAAg");
this.shape_6.setTransform(1.2,-0.9);
```

I want to convert :

```js
this.shape_6.graphics.f("#003366").s().p("AkyEmQgDgHABgPQACgQgDgGQgGgNgBgGQgCgFACgHIABgOQAAgGgFgKIgHgSIAAgMQABgIgBgDQgBgKgDgJQgHgQgDgSQgDgUgDgKQgFgLgBgEQgBgEABgGIAAgKQAAgHgCgKIgFgQIgGgcQgEgWgJgWIgHgUIgCgFIABAAIAVgKQAQgGAcgFQAGgFAIgEQARgKAUgDIAAAAQAHAAAHAEIAFgEIABgBIAFAHQACAEAAAFQADAEACAEQADAJACAgQAHAmAAAUIgCAZIACAJIgBAYQgBAPACAJIAGASQAEAMABAGQABAKgBAOIgCAYQgDATAIAJQAGAGAJAAQAJAAADgGQACgDgBgFIAAAAIBpgnIABACQAAAEAHAIQAEAIAAARIgBAxIAAAQIgHAAIABABIhiAhQgaAIgMACIgjAGIglAKIgWAHIgBgDgAG8D1IgMggIgGgVQgGgagOgZQAogkAmguIAqg1QAGgGAIgJQAFgKAEgEIADgBQAJgBACgHQABgHgHgJIgdgpQgIgLgFgFQgUgbgLgMQgPgPgQgKQAZgXAPgRQAKgPAJgJQAKgHALgFQAJAQAdAgQAbAeAJATQALAVAGAGQAFADAGACIADABQAHADAIgCQAGgCAGgGIALgKQAOgQAigWIAlgZQAKAHALAOIAUAXIAZAZQAJAKAJADIgJAIIgbAZIgcAXIg+A2IgOAJIgNAKQgfAZgHAHQgcAYgyAzQgzA0gaAXQgjAfgTASIgBgCgAsYDqIgSABIABgRQgJgPgCgcIgHhjQgCgPAGgJIAFgGQAAgQgCgLQgBgJgGgQIgBggIAAgfIgEggQgHg1gDg9QgDgJADgHIACgCIgEgFIAJAAIAJgCQAEgCACgGIAEgGQA/AAB2AQQAoAFAYAGQAYAGAcAOQAKAFAQAKQAVAQAKANQAMARACAUQABAYgNARIgRAUIgQAWQgJANgJAHQgJAHgXAIIg5ASQghAMgbAFIgaAGQgPAFgJAFIgDACIABAGQAIAaACAkIADA+QAAANgCAJIABAGIgCAAIgEAHQgIAPgbAKQgOAEgMAAQgOAAgLgFgArZhoQgHAGAAAFQAAAEAGAIQAEAFAAAJIACAQQAAAQAHAJIAAAAQAEABADAFQAIADAOAAIAagBQAMgBAOgHIAYgOQASgMADgMQACgJgHgOQgEgIgFgDQgEgDgHgCIgMgBIg+gEQgRAAgCgGIgMAAQgBADgHAHgABYDNQgIAAgMgEIgUgHQgPgGgXgEIgcgFIgBgHIgBgMQAAgJAFgRQAFgRABgIIABgLIAAgMQAAgDADgFIAEgIQABgGAAgLIAAgSQgCgPACgKQAAgCAEgFIADgGQABgFAAgKIAAgQQABgGAGgKQAEgLgDgXQgBgNADgOQAHgOAAgDQACgGgBgMQgBgNACgGQAAgDAFgIQAEgIAAgFIAAgIQgBgGABgDIADgJQADgFAAgDQADgHgBgOQgCgPADgGIACgEQALABAMgDIAYgEQAUgDAGgCIAVgIQAOgEAJgBIAQgBQAKAAAGgCIAEATIASBOIAEAVIAEAWQACALACAEIAGASIAJAiIAJAgIARA6QAEAIACAJIADAUIAFAQQAFAMAEAPQAEAMAEAIIAHAPQAGANAEATIgBAAIhZATQgIADgFgDQgGgDAAgKQgDgdgRgaIgEAAQgDgEgDgBIAAgCIggAIQgPAFgGAEQgIAEgGAJQgEAHAAAJIgBAPQAAAKgCAGIgDAIIgEAJIAAAJIAAAJIAAACIgLgBgACAhdQgEACgCACQgEAGAAAIIgCAyQgCATgDAHQgGAKgBAEQgBAGAEAGQADAGAGACQAEACAIAAIANABQAVACAHgKQAEgGgEgLIgFgIQgDgFAAgBIgBgKQAAgHgBgEIgGgJQgDgFABgKQABgKgCgFIgEgFQgDgDAAgCIgBgHIgBgFQAAgHgHgCQAAAAAAAAQgBgBAAAAQgBAAAAAAQgBAAAAAAIgDAAg");
```

to a svg file and then convet to this code and remplace the text

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the SVGExporter class that ships with EaselJS.
https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/extras/SVGExporter

```
var exporter = new SVGExporter(this.shape_6, false, false, false);
exporter.run();
document.body.appendChild(exporter.svg);
```

This will create an SVG for you, which you can do whatever you want with.

I [reverse-engineered](https://jsfiddle.net/c3xohm90/1/) the `.decodePath()` method to console.log the raw instructions and quickly output what your contents look like. It is just shape data, so I am not sure how you intend to change the text.

Hope that helps.